# How to annotate pandas date-time format in Matplotlib like Plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How to add annotate text example `1st Lockdown, 2nd Lockdown` in Matplotlib like Plotly?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example using [`ax.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html), as another answer suggested:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dr = pd.date_range('02-01-2020', '07-01-2020', freq='1D')

y = pd.Series(range(len(dr))) ** 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dr, y)

ax.annotate('1st Lockdown',
            xy=(dr[50], y[50]), #annotate the 50th data point; you could select this in a better way
            xycoords='data', #the xy we passed refers to the data
            xytext=(0, 100), #where we put the text relative to the xy
            textcoords='offset points', #what the xytext coordinates mean
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"), #style of the arrow
            ha='center') #center the text horizontally

ax.annotate('2nd Lockdown',
            xy=(dr[100], y[100]), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(0, 100), textcoords='offset points',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"), ha='center')
```

[image]

There are **lots** of options with annotate, so I would [look for an example](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html) that matches what you want to do and try and follow that.

Annotations seem to be the "smart" way of doing this in `matplotlib`; you could also just use `axvline` and `text`, but you will likely need to add extra formatting to make things look nicer:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dr = pd.date_range('02-01-2020', '07-01-2020', freq='1D')

y = pd.Series(range(len(dr))) ** 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dr, y)

ax.axvline(dr[50], ymin=0, ymax=.7, color='gray')
ax.text(dr[50], .7, '1st Lockdown', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), color='gray')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
ax.annotate('1st Lockdown', ...)
```

See https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/text/annotations.html#plotting-guide-annotation

Comment: I want to add 1st Lockdown, 2nd Lockdown against dates like 2020-03-26 and etc. How to do that